# Why does my program run when I have one class, but not when I use two?

Tags: c#

I'm learning how to program in C# and I created a program with two classes that didn't work. The program would run only the first class, and the second class was never executed.

```
using System;
class Swapper
{
       public void Swap(ref double x, ref double y) 

    {
        double temp = x; //copy x into temp
        x = y; //copy y into x
        y = temp; //copy temp into y (copy the original value of x into y)
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Swapper switcher = new Swapper();
        var first = 10.5; var second = 10.6;
        Console.Write("first=" + first + "\nsecond=" + second + "\n"); // before swap
        switcher.Swap(ref first, ref second);
        Console.Write("first=" + first + "\nsecond=" + second + "\n"); // after swap

    }
}

class Swapper2
{
    public void Swap2(ref dynamic x2, ref dynamic y2)
    { 
        dynamic temp2 = x2; 
        x2 = y2; 
        y2 = temp2; 
    }

    static void Main2()
    {
        Swapper2 switcher2 = new Swapper2();
        dynamic first2 = 6549744554; dynamic second2 = 10.6M;
        Console.Write("first=" + first2 + "\nsecond=" + second2 + "\n"); 
        switcher2.Swap2(ref first2, ref second2);
        Console.Write("first=" + first2 + "\nsecond=" + second2 + "\n"); 

    }
}
```

After that, I placed everything in one class and it did run as I wanted:

```
using System;

class Swapper
{
    public void Swap(ref double x, ref double y) 

    {
        double temp = x; //copy x into temp
        x = y; //copy y into x
        y = temp; //copy temp into y (copy the original value of x into y)
    }

    public void Swap2(ref dynamic x2, ref dynamic y2)

    {
        dynamic temp2 = x2;
        x2 = y2;
        y2 = temp2;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Swapper switcher = new Swapper();
        var first = 10.5; var second = 10.6;
        Console.Write("first=" + first + "\nsecond=" + second + "\n"); // before swap
        switcher.Swap(ref first, ref second);
        Console.Write("first=" + first + "\nsecond=" + second + "\n"); // after swap


        Swapper switcher2 = new Swapper();
        dynamic first2 = 6549744554; dynamic second2 = 10.6M;
        Console.Write("first=" + first2 + "\nsecond=" + second2 + "\n");
        switcher2.Swap2(ref first2, ref second2);
        Console.Write("first=" + first2 + "\nsecond=" + second2 + "\n");

    }
}
```

However, I do not understand what happened. 
Why did the first method not work if the code is correct? Why would it stop after running the first class (Swapper) and did it not run the next one (Swapper 2)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to read up on some of the basics of C# programming. Try [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/hello-world-your-first-program#main-method) for information about the `Main` method

Comment: When you first named the method in `Swapper2` as `Main`, did you not get an error message? Did that error not give you an inkling of the problem to come?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the code stopped because it finished executing what's inside of the `Main` method, and since `Main` is the only entry point for the application `Main2` is never executed. you would have to:

1. Change `Main2` [access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) to `internal` or `public`
2. Then Since `Main2`and `Swapper2` are [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) call them using `Swapper2.Main2()` inside the body of `Main` in `Swapper`